# If xsinθ = ysin(θ + 2π/3) = zsin(θ + 4π/3) then prove that Σxy = 0?

Tags: trigonometry

Please help! I don't know how to solve this question.
I tried putting the whole thing equal to "k" and then calculating values of x,y and z in terms of k and putting there. But it messes up the question even more. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I have no clue what Σxy means but I assume it means xy + yz + zx = 0

Comment: What does $\Sigma xy$ mean?

Comment: I seriously don't know. My best guess is it means xy + yz + zx = 0

This question just popped up in my exercise and has weird syntax. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your guess is correct and we are trying to find $xy+yz+zx$. . .

Case 1: $x=0$.  Since $\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)$ and $\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)$ cannot both be zero we have $y=0$ or $z=0$, and so
$$xy+yz+zx=yz=0\ .$$

Case 2: $x\ne0$.  Then
$$\eqalign{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2}
  &=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{x}+\frac{y}{x}\frac{z}{x}\cr
  &=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)}
    +\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)}
    +\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)}\cr
  &=\frac{(\sin\theta)(\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)+\sin(\theta+2\pi/3))+\sin^2\theta}{\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)}\cr
  &=\frac{(\sin\theta)(\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)+\sin(\theta-2\pi/3))+\sin^2\theta}{\sin(\theta+2\pi/3)\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)}\ .\cr}$$
Now use a standard trig formula to simplify $\sin(\theta+\alpha)+\sin(\theta-\alpha)$.

Comment: I would seriously give you a cookie if I were there. A big cyber hug from me.
But please can you elaborate on how this sin(θ+4π/3)+sin(θ+2π/3) got converted to sin(θ+2π/3)+sin(θ−2π/3) ? I couldn't catch this step. Instead I converted that to (2sin(θ+π)cos(2π/3)) which gives 2sin^2θ in the numerator.

Comment: Just $\sin(x)=\sin(x-2\pi)$, so$$\sin(\theta+4\pi/3)=\sin((\theta+4\pi/3)-2\pi)=\sin(\theta-2\pi/3)\ .$$There are other methods which will also work fine.

Comment: Ahh that is my weakest area in this topic. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Hey, can you answer this question too? I will be very grateful to you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935816/if-%CE%B1-%CE%B2-are-two-values-of-%CE%B8-satisfying-equation-cos%CE%B8-a-sin%CE%B8-b-1-c-then-prove

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\sin\left(3A\right)=\sin3A,$

$\sin3\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+A\right)=\sin3A$ and $\sin3\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+A\right)=\sin3A$

So, if $\sin3x=\sin3A,3\sin x-4\sin^3x=\sin3A\iff4\sin^3x-3\sin x+\sin3A=0$

The roots of the above cubic equation are $\sin A,\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+A\right),\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+A\right)$

Using Vieta's formula, $\implies\sum \sin A=\dfrac04$

$\implies\sum\sin A\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+A\right)=-\dfrac34$

$\implies\sin A\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+A\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+A\right)=-\dfrac{\sin3A}4$

Comment: This was an interesting way of doing it but I can't understand how that proves Σxy = 0 Sorry but can you please elaborate it further? This was really short and I plan on using it once I get a good hold of it. :)

Comment: @Shubham, If $x\sin\theta=\cdots=k, \frac1x=\frac{\sin\theta}k$ So, $$\sum xy=xyz(\sum\frac1z)=0$$

Comment: Sorry I still couldn't understand :(( Can you please write the complete solution and then maybe I will ask which steps aren't clear to me. It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: @Shubham, We have $$xy+yz+zx=xyz\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)=\frac{xyz}k\left(\sin A+\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+A\right)+\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+A\right)\right)=?$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understood completely :)